# Error: Emitter Failure Undefined Binding <MusicBinding> in the WSDL Document

Tags: web-services, wsdl

Here is my code currently, cannot find a way of making this compile, any ideas why not?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Lee Wishaw

```
<xsd:schema
 targetNamespace="urn:Music"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">             <!-- start schema -->

  <complexType name="trackDetail">               <!-- start 'trackDetail' type -->
    <sequence>                                         <!-- start fields -->
      <element name="discNumber" type="xsd:integer"/>         <!-- 'disc' field -->
      <element name="trackNumber" type="xsd:integer"/>        <!-- 'track' field -->
      <element name="composerName" type="xsd:string"/>       <!-- 'composer' field -->
      <element name="workName" type="xsd:string"/>          <!-- 'work' field -->
      <element name="titleName" type="xsd:string"/>         <!-- 'title' field -->
    </sequence>                                          <!-- end fields -->
  </complexType>                                <!-- end 'trackDetail' type -->

</xsd:schema>                                            <!-- end schema -->
```

```
<operation name="getByComposer">                <!-- start 'getByComposer' operation -->

  <documentation>                     <!-- start 'getByComposer' documentation -->
    The approve operation takes a search with a composers name,
    and returns the details about the track.
  </documentation>                      <!-- end 'getByComposer' documentation -->

  <input message="getByComposerMessage"/>            <!-- input of 'getByComposer' -->
  <output message="resultMessage"/>              <!-- output of 'result' -->
  <fault name="notFound" message="errorMessage"/>
                                    <!-- fault 'notFound' message 'error' -->
</operation>                                <!-- end 'getByComposer' operation -->


<operation name="getByDisc">                <!-- start 'getByDisc' operation -->

  <documentation>                     <!-- start 'getByDisc' documentation -->
    The approve operation takes a search with a disk number,
    and returns the details about the track.
  </documentation>                      <!-- end 'getByDisc' documentation -->

  <input message="getByDiscMessage"/>            <!-- input of 'getByDisc' -->
  <output message="resultMessage"/>              <!-- output of 'result' -->
  <fault name="notFound" message="errorMessage"/>
                                    <!-- fault 'notFound' message 'error' -->
</operation>                                <!-- end 'getByDisc' operation -->
```

```
<soap:binding style="rpc"
  transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>    <!-- rpc binding -->

<operation name="getByComposer">                <!-- start 'getByComposer' operation -->
  <soap:operation soapAction=""/>                 <!-- empty SOAP action -->
  <input>                                  <!-- start 'getByComposer' binding -->
    <soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:Music"
     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                                                   <!-- literal encoding -->
  </input>                                   <!-- end 'search' binding -->
  <output>                                     <!-- start 'result' binding -->
    <soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:Music"
     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                                                   <!-- literal encoding -->
  </output>                                      <!-- end 'result' binding -->
  <fault name="notFound">                    <!-- start 'notFound' binding -->
    <soap:fault use="literal" namespace="urn:Music"
     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                                                   <!-- literal encoding -->
  </fault>                                    <!-- end 'notFound' binding -->
</operation>                                <!-- end 'getByComposer' operation -->

<operation name="getByDisc">                <!-- start 'getByDisc' operation -->
  <soap:operation soapAction=""/>                 <!-- empty SOAP action -->
  <input>                                  <!-- start 'getByDisc' binding -->
    <soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:Music"
     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                                                   <!-- literal encoding -->
  </input>                                   <!-- end 'search' binding -->
  <output>                                     <!-- start 'result' binding -->
    <soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:Music"
     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                                                   <!-- literal encoding -->
  </output>                                      <!-- end 'result' binding -->
  <fault name="notFound">                    <!-- start 'notFound' binding -->
    <soap:fault use="literal" namespace="urn:Music"
     encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                                                   <!-- literal encoding -->
  </fault>                                    <!-- end 'notFound' binding -->
</operation>                                <!-- end 'getByDisc' operation -->
```

```
<documentation>                      <!-- start 'music' documentation -->
  This is a music search service that returns a tracks details based on the
  composers name or disk number.
</documentation>                
<!-- end 'music' documentation -->

<port name="musicPort" binding="MusicBinding">
                                              <!-- start 'music' port -->
  <soap:address
   location="http://localhost:8080/active-bpel/services/MusicPort"/>
                                                       <!-- SOAP address -->
</port>                                         <!-- end 'music' port -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Your binding element needs to have name attribute, this name attribute needs to be referenced in the port element. This reference however needs to be a QName, so it should be something like "tns:MusicBinding" where tns is bound the WSDL's targetNamespace.